# Condition within map produces an error in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, eslint

I am making a condition that when it is fulfilled, I return an html in the "Return".

Next, my code will be

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './style.css'

const query = gql`
  {
    posts {
      rows {
        id
        autor
        views
        tags {
          id
          titulo
        }
      }
      count
    }
  }
`

export class ColumScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { currentIndex: 0 }
  }

  render() {
    //  const { autor } = props;

    const { data, first, id } = this.props
    if (data.loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    if (data.error) {
      return <div>{data.error.message}</div>
    }
    const {
      data: {
        posts: { rows },
      },
    } = this.props

    rows.map((item, i) => {
      if (item.id === parseInt(id)) {
        return (
          <div className="containerAutor">
            <Link to="/#">
              <img alt="#" className="imagenAutor" src="#" />
              <div className="nombreAutor">{'Author'}</div>
            </Link>
          </div>
        )
      }
    })
  }
}

ColumScreen.propTypes = {
  autor: PropTypes.string,
}

ColumScreen.defaultProps = {
  autor: null,
}

const queryOptions = {
  options: props => ({
    variables: {
      id: props.id,
    },
  }),
}

export default graphql(query, queryOptions)(ColumScreen)
```

In the condition part, there are several items when the query is made, therefore, each **item.id** compares it with the **id** that I send to the component.

For example, there are 10 items with id: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and I compare it with the id 10. If it's the same, then I want to return the html below and thus excluding the other items.

However, an error occurs when I do it, since nothing is shown and I see an error in the Chrome console:

> Uncaught Error: ColumScreen(...): Nothing was returned
>   from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to
>   render nothing, return null.

How could I make this work? I really do not know what happens.

Thank you!

Comment: A component must return at least one jsx element. In your case inside map you I have if condition if condition is true then you are returning otherwise you are not returning anything so you need else condition inside map and that should return at least one jsx element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the result of `map`, and you want to `filter` the `rows` first as well instead of doing the `if` statement inside the `map`.

```js
export class ColumScreen extends Component {
  state = { currentIndex: 0 };

  render() {
    const { data, first, id } = this.props;

    if (data.loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    if (data.error) {
      return <div>{data.error.message}</div>;
    }

    const {
      data: {
        posts: { rows }
      }
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {rows
          .filter(item => item.id === parseInt(id))
          .map((item, i) => (
            <div className="containerAutor" key={item.id}>
              <Link to="/#">
                <img alt="#" className="imagenAutor" src="#" />
                <div className="nombreAutor">{"Author"}</div>
              </Link>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```